# linear search on array of object c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, search

i have a problem with a function ..
I want the function to have two arguments ..
one will be a array of objects and the second one will be the code given by the user
and into the function to run a linear search and check if the user's code exists and if the code exists will return his position in the array else returns -1...

this is what i have try already:

```
int passwdSearch(Eidos pinPro[], int pass)
{
int i=0;
bool found;
found=false;
while(i<N && found==false)
{
    if(pinPro[i].getPasswd()==pass)
    {
        found=true;
        return i;
    }
    else
        return -1;  
    i++;

}
```

}

i want the function return the position if password exist else return symbolic number -1

The problem is that the code return position only for the first element of array and for the 4 others element function return -1

Comment: Hint:  This code can never reach your `i++;`.  You always `return` from the function before reaching that line.

Comment: dude, `std::find_if`

Comment: not all code paths return a value...

Comment: The `found` boolean variable is totally useless. Think about removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else will always be activated if the element is not the first one in the array. you should delete it, and return -1 after the while.

```
int passwdSearch(Eidos pinPro[], int pass)
{
    int i=0;
    bool found;
    found=false;
    while(i<N && found==false)
    {
        if(pinPro[i].getPasswd()==pass)
        {
            found=true;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This way, if you pass through the whole array and you don't find the required element, **then** you would return -1.

**Edit**

And as NathanOliver mentioned, found is useless because you are returning anyways when you find an element. So the code becomes:

```
    int passwdSearch(Eidos pinPro[], int pass)
    {
        int i=0;
        while(i<N)
        {
            if(pinPro[i].getPasswd()==pass)
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `found=true;` is unnecessary as you return from the function on the next line.

Comment: @nathanOliver true, I just quickly changed it so that it works, ill edit, thanks.

Comment: Missing `i++`. Also note that this is c++ and you can use a for-loop `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int passwdSearch(Eidos pinPro[], int pass)
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(pinPro[i].getPasswd()==pass)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice cleanup there.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
int passwdSearch(Eidos pinPro[], int pass)
 {
   int i=0;
   bool found;
   found=false;
   while(i<N && found==false)
   {
      if(pinPro[i].getPasswd()==pass)
      {
        found=true;
        return i;
      }
     else
       i++;
   }
  return -1;
}
```